# Make %o work in console.assert under Jest

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs, babeljs

I'm using jest (on top of babel/webpacker) to test my code but when I use assertions (console.assert) in jest I don't get the expected output.

If I run the following code in the node console I get a message like follows

```
art = {}
console.assert(false, "art not in user_articles art: %o", foo)
Assertion failed: art not in user_articles art: {}
```

But when I get an assertion failure in a jest test I get output like the following:

```
console.assert(user_articles.includes(art), "art not in user_articles art: %o", art)
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: art not in user_articles art: %o
```

Note that unlike when I run the assertion in the console %o isn't replaced with the value of the next parameter.  What do I need to do to make console.assert replace %o with the desired parameter when I run it under jest?

Comment: Why are you using `console.assert` in jest, when it has it's own `expect()`?

Comment: Because the code is being included from a module which has the assert in it.  Eg, I might have a class constructor which has an assert in case it is ever passed inappropriate values but I can't replace that with an expect as it doesn't always run under jest...but I guess I could replace assert when running under jest

Comment: What version of node are you using? [in this jest issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5634#issuecomment-397396673) they state that with node above 10 all environments now comply with the console spec

Comment: 17 and it does throw as required it's just that it doesn't fill in the %o in the output as it does when I run it in the console.

Comment: Sorry should have been *doesn't* throw as required by spec.